# backslash meaning in the C context

Tags: c, backslash

I am reading the C code related to the hardware. I didn't understand the backslash() in the context. what the relationship between the functions?

```
#define timer_wait_us(timerNum, time) \
        timer_set_us(timerNum, time, 0); \
        timer_start(timerNum); \
        timer_wait(timerNum)
```

Answer (score 4):

A `#define` directive exists by default on a single line.  The backslashes are escaping the newline character at the end of the line so that the following line is included as part of the `#define`.

So if you have this in your code:

```
timer_wait_us(timerNum, time)
```

It is replaced with:

```
timer_set_us(timerNum, time, 0);
timer_start(timerNum);
timer_wait(timerNum)
```

Comment: Similarly for a string literal: `char s[] = "one \two";` with the **backslash** at the end of one line and the **two** at the start of the next line. Not as shown in comment where `\t` would be a tab character.

Comment: @WeatherVane: but that form of string literal became obsolete with C90 which allows string literals to be concatenated.  Such code has been obsolete for every single year of the current millennium — and arguably a good while longer.